# Spotify XML request

Tags: xmlhttprequest, spotify

I try to do a XMLHTTPrequest to: `http://lyricwiki.org/api.php?artist=" + encodeURIComponent(artistName) + "&song=" + encodeURIComponent(songName) + "&fmt=xml`

to get the lyrics
but when I look in the inspector Spotify the request status is 0
what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fuller post of your code would help. But I will give this a shot with simplest tested example.

Require this permission in your `manifest.json`:

```
"RequiredPermissions": [
    "http://lyricwiki.org"
],
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure the `manifest.json` file is utf-8 encoded with the proper `\n` only line breaks, and use a JSON linter to verify it is well formatted (http://jsonlint.com/)
Also, Be sure to restart the Spotify client after any changes to `manifest.json`.

This simple example worked for me:

```
    $.post("http://lyricwiki.org/api.php" + 
           "?artist=" + encodeURIComponent("Beastie Boys") + 
           "&song=" + encodeURIComponent("Make Some Noise") + 
           "&fmt=xml", function (data) {
        alert("Data loaded: " + data);
    });
```